# Best way to import shapefile into Redshift via dbt

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, shapefile, dbt

I have a shapefile (DMA area definitions), it's a static data and is not going to change frequently, so I was wondering what would be the best approach to import it into Redshift via DBT.

I'm looking for something similar to dbt seeds, but dbt seeds work only with csv files while what I have is a geo shapefile on s3.

The sql query I'm using to import it from S3 is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dma (
   fid INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   id BIGINT,
   name VARCHAR,
   long_name VARCHAR,
   geometry GEOMETRY);

COPY dma (geometry, id, name, long_name )
  FROM 's3://{somePath}/{someFile}.shp'
  FORMAT SHAPEFILE
  CREDENTIALS '{someCredentials}';
```

So basically I want this import to Redshift be part of my dbt setup instead of running some external sql query manually

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap this in a macro so you could invoke it with something like `dbt run-operation create_dma_table`. For inspiration, you could see this [similar approach for managing UDFs](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/using-dbt-to-manage-user-defined-functions/18).

I would change the `create table` statement to include `replace`, so it's idempotent. I would also add the target schema to the table, so that you can build this in multiple environments (dev/prod/etc).

```
{% macro create_dma_table() %}

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {{target.schema}}.dma (
   fid INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   id BIGINT,
   name VARCHAR,
   long_name VARCHAR,
   geometry GEOMETRY
);

COPY {{target.schema}}.dma (geometry, id, name, long_name )
  FROM 's3://{somePath}/{someFile}.shp'
  FORMAT SHAPEFILE
  CREDENTIALS '{someCredentials}'
;

{% endmacro %}
```

You may also want to explicitly add transaction handling (e.g., `BEGIN...COMMIT`) so this doesn't get rolled back.

Another option would be to poll `information_schema` using [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) or similar for the existence of this table, and add an `if` block to this macro so it only executes if the table doesn't already exist. This would let you run this macro in an `on-run-start` hook to guarantee that this table will always be in your target schema before your dbt runs execute.